# Openstack via Packstack install Public IP Address

Tags: openstack

I have a VM running remotely that I am accessing through a publicly accessible IP address: 125.X.X.X, I SSH'd in and ran `packstack --allinone` and let the process complete.

The IP address on `eth0` is different:

```
br-ex     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr X
          inet6 addr: fe80::e04a:dcff:fe87:501a/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:10 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:684 (684.0 b)  TX bytes:468 (468.0 b)

br-int    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr X 
          inet6 addr: fe80::8093:20ff:fe18:7b65/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:18 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:1320 (1.2 KiB)  TX bytes:468 (468.0 b)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr X
          inet addr:10.50.249.6  Bcast:10.50.249.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fdac:1a8a:2c0a:0:20c:29ff:fe09:6b36/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:fe09:6b36/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:16248 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1042 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1538884 (1.4 MiB)  TX bytes:188487 (184.0 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:74094 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:74094 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:20433087 (19.4 MiB)  TX bytes:20433087 (19.4 MiB)

virbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr X  
          inet addr:192.168.122.1  Bcast:192.168.122.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)
```

So I assume I'm going through some sort of NAT when I run SSH, HTTP, etc.

All the IP addresses in the `packstack` answers file are set to the internal address `10.50.249.6` which is presumably why the dashboard isn't functional - do I need to re-run the script updating the answers file to set all the addresses to my publically facing address to access the *horizon dashboard*?

This is just for demo purposes, so I just want to open the dashboard, and possibly change a few UI components.

Answer (score 0):

In the answers file there is an option to configure controller IP address:

```
CONFIG_CONTROLLER_HOST=192.168.1.10
```

where 192.168.1.10 - IP address of your vm's external network interface

As soon as the packstack installation has been finished, you will see a message like:

```
To access the OpenStack Dashboard browse to http://192.168.1.10/dashboard
```

So Horizon should be accessible via the external IP address.